# LWJGL Getting Started HelloWorld code java exec window not opening

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm on MacOS and using IntelliJ.
I'm relatively new to programming and following [this tutorial](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) from the LWJGL website. I've followed all the instructions and have added -XstartOnFirstThread into my VM options. However, whenever I run the program (HelloWorld.java) in IntelliJ, I see the java exec window in my dock and get "Hello LWJGL 3.2.3 build 13!" in the console, but the window can't be opened and I can't see the window at all.

I've tried running the program from terminal as well, but encounter "package ____ does not exist" errors for every single import. I can't figure out why this is happening.

My code is as down below:

'''

```
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    // The window handle
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        init();
        loop();

        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already 
        the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden 
        after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, 
        repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the 
        rendering loop
        });

        // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
        try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

            // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                    window,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        } // the stack frame is popped automatically

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the 
        framebuffer

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().run();
    }

}
```

'''

EDIT:

So I figured out that the line

```
window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
```

in init() was causing the problem. When the program runs, it just never progresses past this line and I have no idea why or how to fiz it.

Comment: Did you download [the right configuration of LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/customize)? If you are using apple silicon you have to use the early access version.

Comment: I'm not using apple silicon.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to set forward compatibility to true on Mac OS.
Call this in init():

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

Also, you might need to set the OpenGL version.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
// This means you are setting the OpenGL version to be 3.3 (version_major.version_minor)
```

Comment: I tried this because I saw it on another post and it threw an [LWJGL] GLFW_INVALID_VALUE error. I don't think I'm using an OpenGL version that would need that.